# How I can make change of active class on nav li when the page is scrolling, relative to sections?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I need that when the page is scrolling on my fixed-top navbar changes active class of links. How I can do this with jquery? Sections doesn't have fixed height.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse main-navigation fixed-top">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center content-nav-wrapper col-10 offset-1">
                <h1 class="mr-auto"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/site_logo.png" alt="logo"></a></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right offcanvas-toggle menu-button" type="button"
                        data-toggle="offcanvas"
                        data-target="#js-bootstrap-offcanvas" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-offcanvas navbar-offcanvas-touch navbar-offcanvas-right menu"
                     id="js-bootstrap-offcanvas">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<section class="d-flex about" id="about">
<!--Content-->
</section>

<section class="d-flex portfolio" id="portfolio">
<!--Content-->
</section>

<section class="d-flex team" id="team">
<!--Content-->
</section>

<section class="d-flex contact" id="contact">
<!--Content-->
</section>
```

I already have smooth scroll to the section on click. Maybe it just need to be modified?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: If you only care about adding the active class when someone clicks on a link, you can simply use `$(this).addClass('active-class');` within your click function. If you want it to also work when a user manually scrolls to a section, you will have to have some way of associating each section with a link and then add some code to [detect when that element is scrolled into view](https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/how-to-detect-if-an-element-is-scrolled-into-view-using-jquery) and then add a class to the corresponding link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution, works perfectly.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var $sections = $('section');
    $sections.each(function(i,el){
        var top  = $(el).offset().top-100;
        var bottom = top +$(el).height();
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        if( scroll > top && scroll < bottom){
            $('a.active-section-link').removeClass('active-section-link');
            $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').addClass('active-section-link');

        }
    })
});

$("nav").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 800);
});
```